# Bulk create not update in drf

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying bulk update by action decorator but instead new data are created.

My example:

```
@action(methods=['put'], detail=False)
    def car_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = CarSerializer(data=request.data, many=True, context={'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

Using my endpoint (/api/car/car_update) a new entry is created.

Example, I pass the JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id" 2,
        "color": "blue",
        "amount": 3
    }
]
```

But I receive a new:

```
[
    {
        "id" 3,
        "color": "blue",
        "amount": 3
    }
]
```

When I try to pass a instance, like this:

```
...
car = Car.objects.get()
        serializer = CarSerializer(instance=car, data=request.data, many=True, context={'request': request})
```

I received:

```
get() returned more than one Car -- it returned 13!
```

**update 1**

my serializer example:

```
class GarageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Garage
        fields = "__all__"

class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = "__all__"
```

my view example:

```
class GarageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Garage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GarageSerializer
    model = Garage

class CarViewSet(RestrictedQuerysetMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Car.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarSerializer
    model = Car

    @action(methods=['put'], detail=False)
        def car_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            serializer = CarSerializer(data=request.data, many=True, context={'request': request})
            if serializer.is_valid():
                for instance in serializer.data:
                    Car.objects.get(id=instance['id']).update(**instance)
                return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used DRF, but in django you couldn't do this

```
car = Car.objects.get()
```

You would need to do something like this

```
car = Car.objects.get(id=..)
```

or something other than id=..  that would still **uniquely** identify your car instance, as .objects.get only allows the selection of one instance. This is not to be confused with REST 'get' which is a different thing

Comment: thank you @amchugh89. My question is how to caught all "ids".

Answer (score 1):

If I may understood it correctly now, you want to update all the objects by giving their ids inside the data sent through the request. What you want it is not implemented by default, so you could use this example as a mixin if you want to implement it for more views:

```py
    serializer = CarSerializer(data=request.data, many=True, context={'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            for instance in serializer.data:
                Car.objects.get(id=instance['id']).update(**instance)
```

Anyway, I would advise to handle the exceptions thrown by the non existance of the ids you want to modify.

Comment: That's what I thought. Using your example, I get: `update () argument after ** must be a mapping, not list`

Comment: @JoeyFran I just adapted my answer to what I understood you got an error from. Feel free to reach me in order to get further clarifications!

Comment: Hey @ángel-jímenez thank you for support. I changed here and I receive now `KeyError at ... 'id'`. I'm looking for this error and some people suggest to use "serializer.validate_data" instead "serializer.data" or "pk" instead "id". I tried both, but the same thing.

Comment: @JoeyFran I would appreciate if you could give me the data sample you are currently trying to test this with so I can give you further insights. From that error, I guess that you have at least one of your entities with no `id` inside.